# Is there a relationship between цель and "Ziel" (german)?

Tags: этимология, заимствования

The other day I learned Russian word "цель".

It struck me how similar it sounded to the German word "Ziel".

Is there a connection or is it just a coincidence that they sound similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like many word of German origin it came through Polish, here’s relevant quote from [wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C) (which, can not help but notice is almost always best starting point when you have a question about etymology):

> Borrowed from Polish cel (“aim, goal”), in turn from Middle High
>   German zil.

By the way, there’s a bunch of other relatively recent borrowing from German many Russians got used to that extent that it doesn’t feel like a foreign word - [«штука»](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%88%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0)would be my favorite example.

Comment: Wow this is fascinating. Thank you!

Comment: https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5:%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B2_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5

Comment: My favourite example of this kind is ярмарка. Can you guess what German word it's based n?

Comment: @SergeySlepov hmm it sounds a bit like Markt, but I don't know about the Ya at the start. Maybe it was borrowed from earlier times before the German word became Markt.

Comment: @mathreadler Jahr + Markt ;)

Comment: My favourite is probably Gast гость

Comment: @shabunc Ahaa! Of course it is a yearly market! I should have realized :)

Comment: @mathreadler - _Гость_ is not a borrowing from German, it's an originally Slavic word, but it is a cognate with the German _Gast_, both derive from the Proto-Indo-European _*gʰóstis_ 'stranger, guest, enemy'. Latin _hostis_ 'enemy' (like in English 'hostile') also is derived from the same PIE root.

Comment: @Sergey Slepov yearly celebration/festival, I think. Not market.